# Creating a multi tenant rails app. Each tenant must have an owner and other members. How can I accomplish that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, multi-tenant

So I want to build a multi tenant app using Postgres schemas.

People can create a "site" and become its owner. And each site can have many Members.

The owner needs to be able to login to site.app.com/admin to manage his site.

I'm so confused and don't know where to start.

I don't know if I should put the Owner in the public schema or in its Site schema.

Can someone clarify this please.

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to look at the [`apartment` gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you'll need to consider both the server configuration itself (i.e. have one application server and use a catch-all methodology to *translate* passed subdomains to a '*site identifier*' in your application itself), and the application's structure (i.e. have a single application with a number of tables (as you usually would), and store a '*site identifier*' in each table to retrieve the correct data for the site).

With regards to simplifying future maintenance and avoiding serious code complexity, I would personally do something like this:

**Application Server configuration**

- Set up an Nginx server with a 'catch-all', which uses the same document root as the application itself.
  i.e.

Source: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    access_log logs/default.access.log main;

    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root  /var/www/default/htdocs;
  }
```

---

**Rails Application**

- Add a before_filter to your ApplicationController that retrieves the currently used subdomain, and creates a variable that you can use in queries, etc, like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :get_current_site_scope

   private

   def get_current_site_scope
    if sesssion[:current_site_scope].nil?
      session[:current_site_scope] = request.subdomain
    end

     # return the existing @current_site_scope variable, if not null
     # otherwise, set it to the session value (set above) and return it
     @current_site_scope ||= session[:current_site_scope]
   end
end
```

This will store the current subdomain in the current session, under the :current_site_scope key, and will allow you to use `@current_site_scope` in any controller that inherits from the ApplicationController.

Once you've added a *site* attribute to each site-related database table, you can then retrieve site related data by modifying each Active Record query to use this. i.e.

```
articles = Article.find_by(site: @current_site_scope)
```

This is one of the ways that I would do something like this, but it may not necessarily be the best way.

Before you start jumping into code, however, I would strongly advise that you draw your plan out on paper (or whatever planning method helps you the most), and spend some time considering the architecture and it's constraints/issues. A structure like this could become **very** messy and confusing very, very quickly, if not thoroughly planned and carefully executed. :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm so confused and don't know where to start.

I'll detail how you should do it (it will be quite abstract)...

---

Your schema should have `accounts` and `users`.

An `Account` is a "site" (IE has a `subdomain`), and is the scope around which you'll build your data.

You'll have:

```
#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :users, through: :memberships, > { extending AddRole }
end

#app/models/membership.rb
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :role
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :accounts, through: :memberships
end

#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

This will set up the `Account` to have a series of *memberships*, to which you can add "roles". The roles will give you the ability to authorize different activities - either using [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or similar.

--

The above will give you the ability to open an `account` (a "site"), to which you'll then be able to add `users` with the appropriate role.

The *scoping* aspect will happen through the `account` model. I'm not hugely experienced with `PGSQL`'s scoping, but according to the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switching-tenants-per-request), you're able to capture the "account" via the `Subdomain", to which you'll be able to scope your data.

You can capture the `Account`'s subdomain using some constraints in the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: AccountSubdomain do
   root "application#index"
end

#lib/account_subdomain.rb
module AccountSubdomain

    def initializer(router)
        @router = router
    end

    def self.matches?(request)
        Account.exists? request.subdomain #-> use "friendly_id" to make "slug" to act as subdomain
    end

end
```

This will only allow you to access: `http://account1.url.com` but not `http://non-account.url.com`, passing the subdomain to the apartment gem so your application can scope the data around it.

---

If you wanted to use the `apartment` gem, you'd be able to scope around the `account`; I've not had much experience with that so I cannot comment on specifics.

I *can* comment on how broad-level scoping works....

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :current_account #-> this would probably be handled by apartment

   def index
     @users = current_account.users
   end

   private

   def current_account
      @current_account ||= Account.find request.subdomain
   end

end
```

Then you'd be able to use:

```
#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.name %>
   <%= user.role %>
<% end %>
```

---

Finally, if you're wondering what the `extending` reference is, it's an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions).

I made my own gem to add "join attributes" to a dependent model. It will allow you to call:

```
@account = Account.find params[:id]
@account.users.each do
  user.role #-> outputs role
end
```

The code is as follows:

```
#app/models/concerns/add_role.rb
module AddRole

      #Load
      def load
         roles.each do |role|
             proxy_association.target << role
         end
      end

        #Private
        private

        #Roles
        def roles
          return_array = []
          through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
              associate = through.send(reflection_name)
              associate.assign_attributes({role: items[i]})
              return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
          end
          return_array
        end

        #######################
        #      Variables      #
        #######################

        #Association
        def reflection_name
           proxy_association.source_reflection.name
        end

        #Foreign Key
        def through_source_key
           proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
        end

        #Primary Key
        def through_primary_key
          proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
        end

        #Through Name
        def through_name
           proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
        end

        #Through
        def through_collection
           proxy_association.owner.send through_name
        end

        #Role
        def items
           through_collection.map(&:role)
        end

        #Target
        def target_collection
           proxy_association.target
        end
end
```

Comment: The apartment gem looks great! Thanks heaps! :)